# App is not listed in Notification Access settings Android

Tags: android, notifications, notification-listener

I am creating an App to access some Notifications, below is my AndroidManifest.xml files. I installed my app but when i go to Notification Access settings of divice, i can't see my app listed in there, can anyone help me with this

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <service
            android:name="com.example.myapp.otp.MyService"
            android:label="@string/service_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.
                 notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>

        </service>
    </application>
```

And here is MyService.class :

```
public class MyService extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Notification mNotification = sbn.getNotification();
        if (mNotification != null) {
            Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

    }
}
```

Comment: are you declaring `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" /> ` ??

Comment: you also need to check whether your app is in the list of **enabled notification listener component**

Comment: Yes, I did that all but it still didn't work

Comment: show where you are check listener component

Comment: i edited, can you check it

Comment: this is not ways to get component

Comment: Can u post an answer two show me how to get it ?

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I have this issue for an app but in context of it being installed in a work profile and wondering if there is a workaround as work apps don't show there.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get the run time permission if your are using API above 22

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                            .BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE}, 1001);
}
```

You will get response in `onRequestPermissionsResult` for above permission

Then in your activity ask user is your app is allowed to access notification by getting *notification listener component*

```
Set<String> listnerSet = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this);
boolean haveAccess = false;
for (String sd : listnerSet) {
   if (sd.equals("your -- package -- name")) {
        haveAccess = true;
   }
}
if (!haveAccess) {
   startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
}
```

Comment: Your code is will make user go to divice 's Notification Access setting but it my app still didn't listed in there

Comment: for that i had mentioned you need to get run time permission

Answer (score 0):

add this filter to your service :

```
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
```

> ```
>     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
>         Intent intent3 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_DETAIL_SETTINGS);
>         ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
>                 getPackageName(),
>                 NLService.class.getName()
>         );
>         intent3.putExtra(
>                 Settings.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_COMPONENT_NAME,
>                 componentName.flattenToString()
>         );
>         startActivity(intent3);
>     }
>
>
>     startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
>     Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NLService.class);
>     startService(intent1);
> ```